# Sharing file descriptors in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use Pythons multiprocessing module to spawn a server to receive UDP messages, modify them a little, and pass them on to a grep process started with the subprocess module.  Since the stdin for a Popen subprocess accepts a file descriptor, that's what I would like to pass it.

The issue I am having is getting a file descriptor that communicates with the server process that I can pass to the grep subprocess.  I have done this in the past using plain os.fork() and os.pipe(), but I would like to use multiprocessing with the spawn start method now.  I have tried taking a write descriptor from os.pipe, making it inheritable, and passing it as an argument to a new process via multiprocess.Process.  When I try to open it in the other process with os.fdopen(fd, 'wb'), I get an OSError for bad file descriptor.  Here is a snipped of the code I have tested.

```
def _listen_syslog(ip_address, port, write_pipe):
    f = os.fdopen(write_pipe, 'wb')
    #do stuff like write to the file



def listen_syslog(ip_address, port):
    r, w = os.pipe()
    os.set_inheritable(w, True)
    proc = mp.Process(target=_listen_syslog, args=(ip_address, port, w))
    proc.start()
    #this process doesn't need to write, so close it
    os.close(w)
    #this is the descriptor I want to pass to a grep subprocess stdin
    #a similar scenario has worked before using os.fork()
    return r
```

Finally, if it's not possible to do this with a pipe created via os.pipe(),  can I use multiprocessing.Pipe(), and use the file descriptors from the connections objects fileno() function to use directly? More importantly, is that safe to do as long as I don't use the connection objects for anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.  I haven't figured out how to use `os.pipe()`, but if I use `multiprocessing.Pipe()`, I can use the file descriptor from each connection object by calling their `fileno()` functions.  Another thing I found is if you want to use the file descriptors after the connection objects are no longer referenced, you have to call `os.dup()` on each file descriptor, or else they will close and you will get a bad file descriptor error when the connection objects get garbage collected.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def _listen_syslog(ip_address, port, write_pipe):
    f = os.fdopen(write_pipe.fileno(), 'wb')
    #do stuff
    

def listen_syslog(ip_address, port):
    r, w = mp.Pipe(False)
    proc = mp.Process(target=_listen_syslog, args=(ip_address, port, w))
    proc.start()
    return os.dup(r.fileno())
```